# How can I get an ASP.NET Core Angular Template to Run without Errors

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I've created a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 Angular Project using Visual Studio for Mac (v8.4.8) and when I run it in debug mode, the following exception is displayed:

"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request

AggregateException: one or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests.  The error output was: ))
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)

InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests.  The error output was:
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)

I have tried the following to fix the problem but nothing has worked:
  1. Ran an NPM Install on the ClientApp (in VS Code)
  2. Upgraded the ClientApp to Angular 9

Any assistance that can be offered to get this working will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to post your code if you want someone to help you find the error.

Comment: Hi Carl, I haven't written any code, I've just created a new project using the ASP.NET Core Angular template in VS for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably your "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" variable in Development enviroment. If you look your Startup.cs file, you will find this lines:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
   spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
}
```

When you upload that code to a server with the developmen variable, the angular CLI cannot be launched a second time, so it crashes and gives that error message.
or you can substitute it for:

```
#if DEBUG
    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
 #endif
```

With this, instead of being activated when the variable is Develop, it will be launched when it is executed locally